# Why there are so many tags without any question related to them?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request, retag-request

Why do these tags exist if they have no associated questions?

Tags: reinterviewing, self-employment, singapore, supplies, untagged, visa, workers-compensation, workplace-routine, phone, quitting, promises, outside-of-workplace, paperwork, multicultural, mexico, masters, library, it-departments, it-industry, inmigration, job-title, jury-duty, customer-relations, demotion, departments, germany, hardware, health, illness, hours, exercise, exit-interview, charity, cliches, assessment, alertness, banking, batna, accommodations, complaint, boss, bosses, headhunter, recruiters and reference.

In my opinion, some of the tags seem like duplicates (like bosses and boss), some seem off topic (like hardware, mexico, singapore, germany), some too specific (like batna) and finally, google told me that `inmigration` should be `immigration`.

Comment: The tags are there to encourage their useage and subscription. For example, demotion may have no questions, but that doesnt mean there wont be any in the future, it encourages new questions to use the correct , ontopic, tags and gives people a chance to follow those tags until those questions appear

Comment: How flags like `hardware`, `mexico`, `singapore` and `germany` are related to **The Workplace** questions?

Comment: I didnt say all of them, would have taken me far too long to explain each one individually

Comment: @RSFalcon7 Because employment laws and culture differ by geographic region, it was decided that country tags would be acceptable to help filter down questions for a specific region. See [Should we have country specific tags?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/25/316) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Let's categorize these tags so that it's easier to identify areas that might need action...

**Tags with just 1 question:**

Ideally, we should determine if these tags are needed. If they don't have any value, they can be removed and replaced with a better tag. But if the tag is something that could come up again or that could help people find this information, then the tag should remain.

- reinterviewing
- self-employment
- singapore
- supplies
- visa
- workers-compensation
- workplace-routine
- phone
- quitting
- promises
- outside-of-workplace
- paperwork
- multicultural
- mexico
- masters
- library
- it-departments
- it-industry
- immigration (fixed spelling)
- jury-duty
- customer-relations
- demotion
- departments
- germany
- hardware
- health
- hours
- exercise
- exit-interview
- charity
- cliches
- assessment
- alertness
- banking
- batna  (Possibly meaning [Best Alternative to a Negotiated Agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_alternative_to_a_negotiated_agreement) )
- accommodations
- complaint

**Tags that are synonyms of other tags:**

These tags are synonyms of other tags. This means that the question can be tagged with either tag and still show up in the same tag search. For instance, searching for the tag "boss" or "bosses" shows me the same 122 results as if I searched for the "management" tag.

Tag synonyms are often used when different people try to use different tags that really identify the same groups of questions.

- Boss and Bosses are a synonym of Management. 122 questions hold this tag.
- job-title is a synonym of title. There are 13 questions with these tags.
- illness and sickness are synonyms. There are 5 questions with these tags.
- headhunter and recruiter are synonyms of recruitment. There are 58 questions with this tag.
- reference is a synonym of references. There are 22 questions with this tag.

**Untagged Questions:**

- "untagged" is a special tag that is used on questions that do not have a tag. Ideally, we should find tags that apply to these posts. Currently, there is only 1 question that has no tags.

Comment: These are the ones from the first list that I think have "legs": reinterviewing, self-employment, workers-compensation, multicultural, it-industry, immigration, demotion, exit-interview, assessment, accommodations

Comment: Tags with only one question eventually get auto-deleted.  IIRC this takes about 6 months.

Comment: @jcmeloni - "legs"? lol.  Can you clarify?

Comment: sorry - have a foundation, something to stand on, [etc.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+legs)

Comment: It appears that most of those tags could probably be removed and the questions retagged as appropriate - reinterviewing -> interviewing - visa -> immigration etc